# Volume under a surface $z=3-2x-y$ and bound by surfaces

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I'm doing a practice problem and the question is to find the volume under the surface $z=3-2x-y$ with a region enclosed by: $x$-axis, $y=2x$ and $x=2$. The answer given was $6.25$ cubic units.
My initial assumption was to use triple integration and integrate with respect to $z$ first, from $0$ to $3-2x-y$, then with respect to y from $0$ to $2x$, and then with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $2$. I got the value $-4$ so my assumptions were incorrect. I tried to visualize the domain using graphs and drawings but it was too difficult and of no help.

Answer (score 1):

No triple integration (you don't have to integrate wrt variable $z$), Only a double integration.

You need first to **make a sketch of your domain of integration** which is a right triangle with vertices $(0,0),(2,0),(2,4)$; you will realize then how to "sweep it" by vertical segments joining point $(x,0)$ to point $(x,2x)$. Otherwise said by considering, for a fixed $x$, points $(x,y)$ with $y$ ranging from $0$ to $2x$, giving the double integral :

$$\int_{x=0}^{x=2}\int_{y=0}^{y=2x} (3-2x-y) dy dx$$

$$=\int_{x=0}^{x=2}[(3-2x)y-\tfrac12 y^2]_{y=0}^{y=2x} dx=\int_{x=0}^{x=2}((3-2x)2x-2 x^2) dx$$

$$=\int_{x=0}^{x=2}(6x-6x^2) dx=[3x^2-2x^3]_{x=0}^{x=2}=12-16=\color{red}{-4}$$

Comment: But the final answer I obtain is $-8$ far from the $6.25$ you should have... Are you sure you have well copied all your data ?

Comment: Yes, although I'm not sure if there was a mistake as I've done the method that you did multiple times over and I still get -4. I first integrate wrt y and get (6x-6x^2). Finally integrating wrt x and obtaining 12-16 = -4. I'm still not sure if this was the right approach as the volume obtained was a negative number. It should be positive right?

Comment: Doesn't integrating **6x - 6x^2/2** give **6 * x^2 - 6 * x^3/3**, then substituting x=2 gives **6 * 4/2 - 6 * 8/3 = 12 - 16?

Comment: @Zain Barakath My bad, you are perfectly right. Thanks ! I have integrated the (now) good solution in my answer